# Get image from google by id

Tags: php, curl, geektool

I have an image on google (just google weather for [location]) and  I would like to download it and display it through geektool. I have seen people use curl for yahoo weather before, but never for google. If you look at the source, the image's id is `"wob_tci"` and I was wondering if you can download and display that image.

The basic url for getting the weather is http://www.google.com/search?q=weather+for+[city]+[state/province/country]

Thanks for taking the time to help a n00b!

Answer (score 1):

1. Make http request with realistic headers (user agent)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   curl \
       -A "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5" \
       -o weather.html \
       "https://www.google.com/search?q=weather%20for%20kazan"
   ```
2. Parse image src with RegEx or XPath...

You'll have more fun if you do it yourself :)

**Updated**

Something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

CITY="kazan"
SAVE_TO="weather.png"
IMAGE_URL=$(\
curl \
  -A "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5" \
  "https://www.google.com/search?q=weather%20for%20$CITY" | 
  grep -Poh 'src="(.+)" id="wob_tci"' |
  cut -d\" -f2
)

curl -o "$SAVE_TO" "https:$IMAGE_URL"
```

Comment: do you have any idea how this can be turned into a single script?